# Android Generics Error: The method is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm developing an Android application and I'm using generics for a part of it. However I'm getting a compiler error that I'm unable to understand.

I have the following architecture:

```
public interface IMakeableEncryptionBundle<T, F> {
  public void setConfigurationFactory(F configurationFactory);
}

public class VigEncryptionBundle 
    implements IMakeableEncryptionBundle<ITextContent, VigConfigurationFactory> {
  @Override
  public void setConfigurationFactory(VigConfigurationFactory configFactory) {
    // Set the factory.
  }
}


public interface IConfigurationFactory { }

public final class VigConfigurationFactory implements IConfigurationFactory { }
```

And I use it like this:

```
private IMakeableEncryptionBundle<
    ITextContent,
    ? extends IConfigurationFactory> encryptionBundle
  = new VigEncryptionBundle();
```

And this is what causes the error:

```
VigConfigurationFactory configFactory = (VigConfigurationFactory) configObj;
encryptionBundle.setConfigurationFactory(configFactory);
```

**"The method setConfigurationFactory(capture#8-of ? extends IConfigurationFactory) in the type IMakeableEncryptionBundle is not applicable for the arguments (VigConfigurationFactory)"**

But isn't this exactly what "extends" is supposed to do? To allow you to use a subclass/implementation in place?

Also neither this is working:

```
encryptionBundle.setConfigurationFactory((IConfigurationFactory) configFactory);
```

**Edit:**
What I'm trying to achieve, is have an independency of the particular `IConfiguration` implementation and put the instantiation of `encryptionBundle` in an external class.

At the same time I need generics to make sure a particular `IMakeableEncryptionBundle` implementation can use it's own `IConfiguration` implementation.

In addition, the following as suggested below gives me another error:

```
private IMakeableEncryptionBundle<
    ITextContent,
    IConfigurationFactory> encryptionBundle
  = new VigEncryptionBundle();
```

**"Type mismatch: cannot convert from VigEncryptionBundle to IMakeableEncryptionBundle"**

I even tried to declare the following with no change:

```
public interface IMakeableEncryptionBundle<T, F extends IConfigurationFactory>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your edit about making the code independent of a particular implementation and putting the instantiation of `encryptionBundle` in another class. Whatever line instantiates `encryptionBundle` is going to depend on the implementation. Do you mean, you want to be able to build an `IMakeableEncryptionBundle` in one class with the `VigConfigurationFactory` and then give it to another class that doesn't know about that particular factory?

Comment: Exactly, the class I'm using `encryptionBundle` in, should not know about the particular factory. And the one that instantiates it would be the external class. That's why I can't use `VigConfigurationFactory` here.

Comment: Do you actually need the `F` type parameter at all, then? Why not just remove it and replace the instance of it in `setConfigurationFactory`'s signature with `IMakeableEncryptionBundle<ITextContent>`?

Comment: I need F to ensure that `setConfigurationFactory` in `VigEncryptionBundle` can only take a `VigConfigurationFactory`. I've changed it to `IMakeableEncryptionBundle<T, F extends IConfigurationFactory>` and I don't understand why it won't accept `setConfigurationFactory(VigConfigurationFactory)` now. It seems like "extends" is doing nothing in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The type `? extends IConfigurationFactory` in `encryptionBundle` means "some type that you don't know that extends `IConfigurationFactory`. (The fact that the variable `encryptionBundle` is assigned to a value that could be given a more precise type is irrelevant; the type checker forgets it right after it checks that the assignment is valid.)

So when you try to call `setConfigurationFactory` on a `VigConfigurationFactory`, the type checker rightfully rejects it: you only know that the `F` that shows up in `setConfigurationFactory`'s argument type is *some* class that extends `IConfigurationFactory`, not that it's `VigConfigurationFactory` in particular.

How you fix this depends on why you wanted to declare `encryptionFactory` with that type in the first place. If it's feasible, then simply changing `? extends IConfigurationFactory` to `VigConfigurationFactory` will work. Otherwise, how you fix the problem will depend on what you were after.

Comment: So from what I understand, "extends" applies only to this one line (the declaration), making sure that the instance used is in the right type.
But then how can I modify the code to achieve what I need? (See edit) I can't use the approach you suggested, as that would result in a dependency from `VigConfigurationFactory`. I've tried pretty much everything and I fail to see how I can utilize generics to work this way.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your code to work by changing

```
private IMakeableEncryptionBundle<ITextContent, ? extends IConfigurationFactory> encryptionBundle = new VigEncryptionBundle();
```

to

```
private IMakeableEncryptionBundle<ITextContent, IConfigurationFactory> encryptionBundle = new VigEncryptionBundle();
```

I'm not too sure of the reasoning behind it, but I'd assume it has something to do with the fact that IConfigurationFactory is an interface.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm getting a type error (see edit). Did you modify the `VigEncryptionBundle` class?

Comment: I'd add this comment above but I have no rep :(

Inline with @jacobm's comment, by changing the interface declaration to <T, F extends IConfigurationFactory>, it seems as if you're always expecting that F generic type to be IConfigurationFactory.  You can do one of two things here to handle what you're trying to do:  remove the F generic parameter and have setConfigurationFactory take a parameter of IConfigurationFactory, or you can change the declaration of VigEncryptionBundle to implement IMakeableEncryptionBundle<ItextContent, IConfigurationFactory>

Comment: The problem is that I don't need F to be IConfigurationFactory, but a particular implementation of it. And I'm trying to ensure that `setConfigurationFactory` in `VigEncryptionBundle` can only take a `VigConfigurationFactory`. I've changed it to `<T, F extends IConfigurationFactory>` and I don't understand why it won't accept `setConfigurationFactory(VigConfigurationFactory)` now.